# Axios: getting two requests OPTIONS & POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to post data. Everything works fine, but I don't know why I'm getting two requests `OPTIONS` & `POST`

POST:
[image]

OPTIONS:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
const url = 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/myusers';

export function postUsers(username, password) {
    let users = {
        username,
        password,
    };
    return{
        type: "USERS_POST",
        payload: axios({
            method:'post',
            url:url,
            data: users,
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: first result in google https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/475

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Non-simple CORS requests via AJAX are pre-flighted. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). This is a browser behavior and nothing specific to axios. There's nothing inherently wrong with this behavior and if it's working for you, you can just leave it.

If you insist on getting rid of it, there are a few ways you can go about:

1. You can set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on your server to disable CORS.
2. Make your CORS request a simple one. You will have to change the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. Not `application/json`.

I'd say just leave it as it is if the `OPTIONS` request is not blocking you.

Comment: Good catch. Fixed the wording.

Comment: HI, yongshun toy grate answer

Comment: I understand what you mean BUT surely setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` does not "disable CORS" - it allows CORS requests from *anywhere*.

Comment: Thanks! The `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` works great