# PHP - process image on heroku without save it on the server

Tags: php, heroku, slim

I'm trying to process images file on heroku. I've created an endpoint that will accept POST request using Slim 4 and on the front-end I'm using vue.

PHP heroku code

```
<?php 
//use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

//$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
//$container = $containerBuilder->build();

//$container->set('upload_directory', __DIR__ . '/tmp');

//AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args){  
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello');
    return $response;
});

$app->post('/compress', function(Request $request, Response $response, Array $args){
    var_dump($args);
    // $payload = $args["payload"];
    // $dir = __DIR__.'/tmp/';
    // //$directory = $this->get('upload_directory');
    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();

    // // handle single input with single file upload
    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['image'];
    var_dump($uploadedFile);
    // if($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    //     //$filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
    //     $im = new Imagick($uploadedFile);
    //     Morpheus\Data::write($payload, $im);
    //     $im->writeImage($dir.'output.jpg');

        //$response->getBody()->write('no error');
    // }
    
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
?>
```

The code is commented because I'm having some trouble to get the data passed from the client using axios. I'm not able to get the payload that is part of the post request I've made. Since I don't want to save the image but only process it, at the moment I'm trying to pass the uploaded file directly to the library that will manipulate it.

VUE client app

```
    handleUpload() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image',  this.$refs.masterImage.files[0]);
// the payload is generated into another method and is an array that I will convert into string
// on the server this will not be recognized
      formData.append('payload', JSON.stringify(this.payload)); 

      let config = {
        header: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        withCredentials: true //only for debug on localhost
      }

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/compress', formData, config)
      .then( (response) => {
        console.log(response, response.data);
      });
    } //
```

How I can use the uploaded file with Imagick without saving it on heroku (I know that the files will be deleted at every dyno restart!) and then pass it back processed so the user can download it? I'm trying to use [morpheus](https://github.com/pyrou/morpheus) a php library for steganography, I want to put the payload inside the image before return it to the user. How I can achive this?

Comment: I can't tell from the post, are you getting anything on the server side? Ignoring routes for a bit. can you dump $_POST and $_FILES and see anything? Are you getting a CORS error at all on the client side, and are you getting an [OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255887/231316) on the server?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm able to get the `$_POST` and the `$_FILES` on the server, what will not work is to pass the uploaded file directly to Imagick to use morpheus library. I'm looking for an upload library that can be integrated with slim to have file validation

Comment: Okay, so we can completely ignore the axios, Vue stuff, right? Although important to your app, for us, that is working and we don't need to worry about? Can you post the results of your `var_dump` statements?